# What is the config to set indent=4 spaces in yeoman

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

By default `yeoman` generate source files with indent = 2 spaces

I wan't to make it 4 spaces by default.

What is the configuration I need to alter?

Comment: Use a tool like e.g. WebStorm and do a reformat of the generated code.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't currently an option for this. You can change it yourself after scaffolding though.

Comment: Thank for the info. Hope they will add something soon.