# Yeoman Ember Generator : How to get 4 spaces per indent in generated codes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying out Yeoman Ember Generator. The files generated are using *2 spaces*, while I want to use **4 spaces** per indent level. How do I go about changing that? Is there a setting somewhere, or do I need to modify the generator-code itself (which I do not know anything about)?

I tried Google, SO, [Ember Generator Github](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember), and the linked mailing list pointed to post questions here [Yeoman Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yeoman-dev/r1sjuApz1Pk), but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that unless you branch form the original repo and change all the templates to use 4 space.

Though that a known issue, so they'll probably fix it soon:
https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/285

Comment: Also dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396088/what-is-the-config-to-set-indent-4-spaces-in-yeoman

Comment: should have searched with yeoman. i thought ember-generator was a separate project aside from the main yeoman. The issue seems to have started in Jun 2013. Where are the template files located? I am absolute beginner to yeoman and ember. Is it [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/tree/master/view/templates)